# Object not found when building a random forest regression

Tags: r, shiny, random-forest, shinydashboard

I am working on my first shiny app, trying to build a `random forest regression` to predict the arrest charge for a Crime Dataset. I got an error said object `offense_category` not found when running the app. I have tried many suggestions online but it's still not working.

[image]

Here is my current ui.R code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                
                #header
                headerPanel("Prediction"),
                #inputs
                sidebarPanel(
                  h2("Filter"),
                  
                  selectizeInput("offense_category", label="Offense Category", choices=c("", sort(unique(df$offense_category))),multiple=FALSE),
                  radioButtons(
                    "year",
                    "Select year",
                    choices = c("2020", "2021","2022","2023"),
                    selected = "2020"
                  ),
                  selectizeInput("neighborhood", label="Neighborhood", choices=c("", sort(unique(df$neighborhood))),multiple=FALSE),
                  actionButton("predictbutton", "Predict", class = "btn btn-primary")
                ),
                mainPanel(h2("Prediction"), 
                          tableOutput(outputId = 'chargeprediction'))
)
```

And my server.R code:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  #input data
  datainput <- reactive({
    result <- data.frame(
      Name = c("Offense Category",
               "Year",
               "Neighborhood"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$offense_category,
                           input$year,
                           input$neighborhood)),
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    Estimate_charge <- 0
    result <- rbind(result, Estimate_charge)
   
    write.table(result, "result.csv", sep="", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
    test <- read.csv(paste("result",".csv",sep=""),header=TRUE)
    
    Output <- data.frame(Prediction=predict(rf,test), round(predict(rf,test,type="prob"),1))
    print(Output)
  })
  output$chargeprediction <- renderTable({
    if (input$predictbutton > 0){
      isolate(datainput())
    }
  })
}
```

And here is the error in console for your reference:

[image]

If the code runs properly, it should output a table containing the predicted result, and the corresponding probability of that prediction.

Random Forest model:
`rf <- randomForest(charge ~ offense_category+year+neighborhood, data=trainingset, ntree=500, importance=TRUE)`

Comment: Don't you need the test data per column? You are specifying the feature names and the values in one column, respectively. The `test` data.frame should have column names `offense_category` (and the other feature names the model was trained with.

Also: Where is the `rf` object of your trained model stored?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ReelSaemon, the `rf` is basically the random forest model I trained and it's stored in the same R script. I understand that `test` data.frame should have column names. But the `test` data frame is just read.csv("result.csv"), in which I have created the column names. I thought it would make the `test` data frame also have column names.

Comment: When you want to have column names you could initialize your `result` like this:

`result = as.data.frame(list(column1="value1", column2="value2", column3="value3"))
`

with `column1, column2, ...` being your feature names from the `rf` model and the `value1, value2,...` the respective test data values.

The feature names from the `result` `data.frame` need to be the same as in `rf`

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by the respective test data values? `Value = as.character(c(input$offense,input$year,input$neighbor)), `                                                                                          In my previous code, the values were the inputs in the ui part. Are they the test data values that you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, at least I think so. I do not know how your Random Forest model is specified. The test set just needs to be of the same structure as your training data.

Comment: Please refer to the Random Forest code I just posted. I have tried your method to rebuild the data frame. I don't know if I have done it correctly and it ends up with the same error.                                                                                                                                `result = as.data.frame( list(offense_category = input$offense_category, year = input$year, neighborhood = input$neighborhood))`

Comment: Then you need a `data.frame` with columns `offense_category`, `year` and `neighborhood` as column names carrying values that have the same type and similar contents that the model can process for your `predict()` call. The `test` `data.frame` you specified in your app has column names `Name` and `Value`. However, if you tried the code specified in your last comment above, that should have worked. I guess the error is happening somewhere else. Have you tried the prediction with `predict()` outside shiny with the same `randomForest` model?

Comment: The error could also stem from the line in the `ui.R`
`selectizeInput("offense_category", label="Offense Category", choices=c("", sort(unique(df$offense_category))),multiple=FALSE)`. Are you sure `df` has a column named `offense_category`? Also, your `selectizeInput` is named `offense_category`. But you are accessing it in the `server.R` with `input$offense`. This could also lead to (other) errors.

Comment: Yes, there is a column called `offense_category` in `df` and I have tried the prediction with `predict()` on the testing dataset and cross validation, both worked. I also changed the names in `selectizeInput` now that the features have the same names everywhere. Unfortunately, it gave me the same error. I suppose it must be wrong somewhere else.